# A parabolic PDE of the form $\partial^2_yf+\partial_x g\partial_xf+\partial_y g\partial_yf=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to solve the following, parabolic homogenous PDE:

$$\partial_y\left[(x^2-y^2)\partial_yf\right]+x\partial_xf+y\partial_yf=0$$

Equivalently, one can write it in the following canonical form:

$$\partial^2_yf+\frac{x}{(x^2-y^2)}\partial_xf-\frac{y}{(x^2-y^2)}\partial_yf=0$$

which also leads to the following form:

$$\partial^2_yf+\partial_x g\partial_xf+\partial_y g\partial_yf=0$$

with $g(x,y)=\log(\sqrt{x^2-y^2})$. I have attempted the method of separation of variables and consulted the *Handbook of linear partial differential equations for engineers and scientists* by Polyanin et al, but couldn't proceed. I am looking for a general solution that I can match with a boundary condition at $f(x, \pm 1)=e^{-\lambda x^2}$. The problem is on the domain $(x,y) \in [1,\infty)\times[-1,1]$

Comment: Idea: assume $f$ is analytic in both dimensions, then substitute a general Taylor-polynomial in two variables for $f$, and try to solve for coefficients? You get infinite matrices for coefficients, but maybe some of the coefficients can be solved, so they can be substituted back to the equation? Many coefficients should be zero based on the equations. Maybe this produces matrix equation that can be easily solved?

Comment: what happens at the corner $x=y=1$?

Comment: Do you want a proof of existence and uniqueness or an explicit formula ? Because those don't exist in general